# Fast Dormancy in 3G devices

Tags: api, mobile, 3g

In a nutshell Fast Dormancy allows the RRC state machine to go to IDLE(CELL_PCH) from CELL_DCH without waiting for the timer to expire. Is there any OS (Android, Windows Phone, iOS etc) which exposes APIs using which we can invoke fast dormancy on 3G devices? Any pointers appreciated.

> EDIT: Does any OS expose API's to
>   switch off 3G radio or switch radio
>   states(DCH,FACH,IDLE etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Blackberry also expose fast dormancy since API 4.0.0

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/IOProperties.html#CDMA_SET_FAST_DORMANCY_FLAG

and

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/io/IOProperties.html

The OFono stack used by MeeGo seems to have Fast Dormancy settings (and radio toggling) in the radio settings api, but I can't really see at which level those would be available to users. The API doc is in their git repo:

http://meego.gitorious.org/meego-cellular/ofono/blobs/5639c653979e324e0b3a195ec3fab07fc2bd3a05/doc/radio-settings-api.txt

I've read NCFD has been blamed for spotty 3G performance on iOS devices in some cases, so I'm not sure programmatically playing with at an application level is such a good idea, especially since you'd be making assumptions about the entire platform's network stack requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly (I'm not familiar with the actual 3G-technology), but at least BlackBerry API (since 4.2.1) does have the following method:

> Requests that the radios belonging to
>   the provided Wireless Access Families
>   be powered off.

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Radio.html#deactivateWAFs(int)

Constants used with the above:
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioInfo.html#WAF_3GPP

Not sure if this is what you actually meant.

Comment: Yes this answers my second question where I asked for API calls for switching off 3G radio.